# Given multiple coordinates (x,y) of a vehicle, how to determine the angle at which the vehicle turns?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, python

Around 20 coordinates of a vehicle's location are mentioned. Everytime the car turns, at what angle does it turn? How to determine the angle? Is there any particular formula to get the angle using coordinates only?

I tried coding it in Python:

```
def turn_angle(x2, y2, x1, y1, rotation=0, clockwise=False):
    angle = degrees(atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)) - rotation
    if not clockwise:
        angle = -angle
    return angle % 360
```

Is the above function correct? Or is there any other alternative method to calculate?

A few coordinates of the vehicle are:

```
(0,0), (-0.2,-0.5), (-0.2,-0.5), (-0.1,-0.6), (0.3,-0.2),(1.2,0), 

(2.6,-0.5), (4.3,-1.2), (5.5,-2.7), (6.5,-4.8), (6.7,-7.8), (5.7,-11.2), 

(3.9,-14.8), (2.2,-17.8), (0.5,-20.8), (-2.1,-24.7), (-4.9,-30), (-8.5,-37.1), 

(-11.9,-44.7), (-14.7,-52.8), (-17.7,-61.8), (-19.9,-70.9), (-21.5,-80), (-23.3,-89.4),

(-24.9,-97.9), (-26.6,-105.6), (-27.8,-112.3), (-28.6,-117.7), (-28.8,-120.1)
```

Comment: Before answering your question we would like to know the following information. How do you determine the values of the two input parameters $\pmb{rotation}$, and $\pmb{clockwise}$ using the value of the output parameter $\pmb{angle}$?

Comment: I assumed it. If I got angles in negative, how would I be able to decide if the vehicle is taking a sharp turn or not? There has to be a limit that decides if the vehicle took a sharp turn or safe turn.

Comment: Please add a list of 20 or so vehicle locations (i.e. x- and y-coordinates) to your problem statement. Which loop are you planning to use in your program to call the function $turn\_angle$, $\pmb{for}$ or $\pmb{while}$?

Comment: I'll add the locations, to call the turn_angle I'm using for loop

Comment: I've added over 20 coordinates to the problem statement.

Comment: Is this a theoretical problem? Practically it is done with accelerometer devices.

Comment: yes it is a theoretical problem

Comment: A car moves in either straight segments, or in arcs. The above is not sufficient information to determine the exact path the car is taking.

Comment: PS The point `(-0.2,-0.5)` is repeated twice which would throw any pathing algorithm literally for a loop of 0 radius. Not good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't seem well-defined. How many turns and by what angle can you see in these four points?

[image]

Comment: Assuming each red point as origin, what is the steering angle of a vehicle. Consider the first path you've drawn. This is how I want to find the angles (marked in red) at which the vehicle turns.
  [Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6goPi.jpg

Comment: @ilanky You said you _'consider the first path'_ I've drawn. But you have no path given, you have just a sequence of points instead. And, as you can see, you can devise many different paths through the same sequence of points. So you need to make _a priori_ some assumptions regarding the possible characteristics of the path, so that you can reconstruct a path from the given set of points. Only then you can try to calculate the heading of a car (geometrically: the direction of a line tangent to the path) at given points.

Comment: Since the data I have only shows coordinates per second, I cannot provide any extra details.

Comment: So you can't do what you want. All four paths I sketched fit same four points, but each of them results in a different direction at each point (except two middle paths at endpoints). If you have no criterion to choose a path, to select 'the correct' one (or 'some good enough', at least) from all possibilities, then there's no way to determine angles. It's like asking about a color of a dog while you don't know which dog it is.

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with the comments, this problem is not well defined.**

A car moves in consecutive arcs and lines. The points provided are not sufficient to define the path of the car.

For example, take three points below:

[image: fig1]

You can either fit one arc through them - case a), or two arcs through them - case b).

The end result has the vehicle pointing in different directions past the 3rd point.

With the points given, the path looks as follows:

[image: fig2]

The sense of direction can be found by the sign of the distance $h$ of the 3rd point from the line connecting the 1st and 2nd points

[image: fig3]

```
m = sqrt((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2)
h = (x_1*(y_2-y_3)+x_2*(y_3-y_1)+x_3*(y_1-y_2))/m
turn = sign(h)
```

Comment: what exactly is h?

Comment: @ilanky look at the diagram. `h` is the perpendicular distance of the 3rd point from the line joining two other points. It can be used to decide if the vehicle is turning left or right based on if it is positive or negative (or zero of 3 points in line).